# Is it good practice to check for user access level at every step of a given process?

Tags: laravel, security

I have a laravel webapp and I check if the user can perform certain actions or access certain information at every step of the way not just during the login. For example when they wish to view their assets I check for their UAC, after they click on them I check again, even if the edit, delete buttons are not visible, there is still a check in place in the code. And this pattern continues throughout the whole webapp. Is this overkill, will it make my webapp too cluttered with checks all over the place?

Comment: Finally, this is one of the "it depends" questions which cannot be answered. But note that you will usually have _implicit_ access checking by using a relational database and searching for user ID. In a `SELECT.... WHERE USER=123` type of query, the user never gets to see something that doesn't belong to him. On the other hand side, note that e.g. absence of a "delete" button does not prevent a malicious user from sending a delete command (even with a random resource id) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.  Every time you *don't* check for access before performing a privileged action, you take the risk that an intruder might find a way to bypass your earlier checks and somehow trigger that action without actually having proper access to it.  A few extra checks are a small price to pay for robustness and peace of mind.

In particular, you should always re-check privileges on the server for each new request made by the client, since [you should never trust user input](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Don%27t_trust_user_input), and since *everything* the client sends to the server is potentially under the user's control.  For example, even if you disable the "edit" or "delete" buttons in the client interface, what's to stop a malicious (or even just inquisitive) user from re-enabling them e.g. through their browser's developer tools, or even from simply spoofing the actual edit/delete request that the button would trigger?

If you're lucky, all a missing server-side privileges check will do is let some user [see a bunch of deleted garbage.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225182/did-you-know-that-10k-users-can-see-deleted-comments)  If you're not so lucky, it might give them full admin access on your site.

Comment: Couldn't have answered this better myself! Very good answer! The only thing I could remotely add would be to set this up as a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a good practice and middleware can help you achieve this goal more easily.

[Check the Laravel documentation for more information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware)